# What role does BASE_PATH play in Angular projects?

Tags: angular, rest, api, swagger, base-path

In order to integrate the "Angular-Typescript-Client-Generated" files generated by Angular in my Angular project, I have to provide the path of the Api (http://localhost:8080). The README file generated by Swagger says:

#### Set service base path

If different than the generated base path, during app bootstrap, you can provide the base path to your service.

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'https://your-web-service.com' },
]);
```

or

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'https://your-web-service.com' ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Using @angular/cli

First extend your `src/environments/*.ts` files by adding the corresponding base path:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_BASE_PATH: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
};
```

In the src/app/app.module.ts:

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [ ],
  providers: [{ provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: environment.API_BASE_PATH }],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried to execute the second method "Using @angular/cli" but unfortunately I can't use

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '';
```

because the error

```
Cannot find module''
```

occurs. I don't really understand who provides the BASE_PATH in the ANgular project.

Could you help me please with some ideas how to set the base path or with some explanation about the process of providing the base_path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [documentation here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular-v4/npm/README.md). BASE_PATH is supposed to be declared in one of the files

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '@swagger/angular2-typescript-petstore';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'https://your-web-service.com' },
]);
```

Comment: Hi Athanasios, thank you for the reply!

I read the documentation, but I can't get some things. Should I copy the api folder (generated by Flask containing the services and models) in the src/app folder of my project? If i want to publish: "npm install @swagger/angular2-typescript-petstore@0.0.1 --save" with what should I replace "angular2-typescript-petstore@0.0.1" the name of my api?